# Setting dynamic src tag to an embedded google map gives an X-frame-options error using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I'm trying to render a certain location using google maps embed iframe (below):

```
<iframe width="100%" height="200" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" marginHeight={0} marginWidth={0} id="gmap_canvas" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?width=520&amp;height=400&amp;hl=en&amp;q=Vereador Abílio Otavio do Canto %20Itaja%C3%AD+(Macaco)&amp;t=&amp;z=15&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;iwloc=B&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

And it renders properly (print below):
[image: Embedded map properly working]

But when i try to set the src tag dynamically (below):

```
<iframe width="100%" height="200" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" marginHeight={0} marginWidth={0} id="gmap_canvas" src={"https://maps.google.com/maps?width=520&amp;height=400&amp;hl=en&amp;q=Vereador Abílio Otavio do Canto %20Itaja%C3%AD+(Macaco)&amp;t=&amp;z=15&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;iwloc=B&amp;output=embed"}></iframe>
```

It gives me the following error (The connection with google.com was refused):
[image: Connection refused]
Console:
[image: Console error print]

My goal is to change the src so i can put a location in a dynamic way, example:

```
src={`https://maps.google.com/maps?width=520&amp;height=400&amp;hl=en&amp;q=${myCustomLocation}&amp;t=&amp;z=15&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;iwloc=B&amp;output=embed`}
```

I don't want to use google API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who struggle with it, i had to use `encodeURIComponent()` method to get rid of the error:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="300" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" marginHeight={0} marginWidth={0} id="gmap_canvas" src={`https://maps.google.com/maps?width=520&height=400&hl=en&q=${encodeURIComponent("Vereador Abílio Otavio do Canto Itajaí (Macaco)")}&t=&z=15&ie=UTF8&iwloc=B&output=embed`}></iframe>
```